# Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Web Edition: is it suitable for "closed" websites?

Tags: sql-server-2008

Can **Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Web Edition** be used in **"closed" websites**, which are hosted on the Internet, but require users to log in?

We are developing a web application for banks. This is a website for clients of the bank; it allows clients to log in and view information on their personal banking accounts, stock portfolios, etc.

Can this web app use SQL Server 2008 Web Edition?

Here is information on this edition of SQL Server:

http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/web.aspx

It is said on this page that Web Edition can be used only on "**public and Internet accessible** ... Web applications". Technically, the web app we are developing is public and Internet accessible - although it requires authentication. Won't using Web Edition in our web app violate SQL Server license terms?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, perfectly. The website is public (everyone can see the login screen) and it is internet accessible (as in: accessed from / through the internet). You probably have a larger public site, actually, with some news and legal discplaimers.

As the authentication you do will be WITHIN the app, it is totally within the limits that the license says.

(and yes, I am SPLA license holder, so I know the SPUR you ahve to follow)

Comment: Does that mean that SQL Server Web Edition can be used to create all kinds of Intranet-like applications, that will be technically accessible over the Internet, but will require authentication and will thus be reserved only to a limited number of users?

And will the cost be limited only to the monthly $15 per processor?

Comment: Theoretically yes, BUT.... you are not allowed to identify users using OS means. This means: account for the website, the resit is to be done wthin the app. Intranet apps rather would love... acive directory integration etc.

I know quite a lot of "non public" websites that fit here. Start with communities (I am part of some that are pretty much invitation only), go over to a company selling project management software that is hosted. All valid uses. Also note the technical limits of web edition.

Check your SPUR ;)

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Tom. As for the technical limits of the web edition: it seems that the Web edition is quite powerful - like the Standard edition in terms of RAM and DB size limitations? Are there any hidden limitations of the Web version? And I am sorry: what is SPUR? :)

Comment: it is QUITE powerfull - but it misses certain areas of the enterprise edition. SPUR--- you obviously are no SPLA customer. SPUR is a HUGH document describing what you area llowed to do under SPLA for every product. Close to 200 pages (like an EULA for everything MS makes). It is called Service Provider Usage Rights... in short SPUR ;)

Comment: This answer might not be correct for 2014+ now. The latest SPUR documentation says: "Additional Terms:

The software may be used only to support public and Internet accessible

    Web pages

    Web sites

    Web applications 

    Web services

It may not be used to support line of business applications (e.g., Customer Relationship Management, Enterprise Resource Management and other similar applications)." ..... so while Sql Server 2008 might have had a different license, 2014 (which now covers 2012 on SPLA) it seems that "line of business" applications cannot be run under web edition.